# Upgrading Azure Blob API 11->12, leading slash in blob name cannot be found in 12

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

My project was built long ago using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob and I have many containers with many files.  I am not sure how it happened but all of my folder structures have a leading slash in them.  This has not been an issue until I try to upgrade my code to Azure.Blobs (v12).
When I look at my blobs in the Azure Portal, it shows a blank / in the root folder, and browsing down I see it looks like this
[container] **/ /** [first folder] / [second folder] / [filename]

Azure portal has not problem showing a file and downloading it. When I look at properties, the URL looks like
https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]//folder1/folder2/file.ext

After updating my code, I find that container.GetBlobClient([folder+filename]) will not retrieve any files.  It always gets a 404. When I look in debugger to see what URL it is trying to access, it is eliminating the double slash so it looks like
https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/folder1/folder2/file.ext

I have tried prepending a slash to the [folder+filename] but it always strips it out. Ditto for prepending two slashes.

I have been googling all day and cannot find an answer here.  Is there a workaround to this?  I am thinking there has to be because both the Azure Portal and Cloudberry Explorer can access and download my blobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible workaround is to create an instance of [`BlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-blobclient-ctor(system-uri-azure-storage-storagesharedkeycredential-azure-storage-blobs-blobclientoptions)) using the full URL of the blob. That way the leading slashes are preserved.

Please take a look at the code below. It makes use of `Azure.Storage.Blobs version 12.10.0`.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

namespace SO71302870
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string accountName = "account-name";

        private const string accountKey = "account-key";

        private const string containerName = "container-name";
        private const string blobName = "/000/1.txt";//notice the leading slash (/) here.
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
            BlobClient blobClient =
                new BlobClient(new Uri($"https://{accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{containerName}/{blobName}"), credential);
            var properties = await blobClient.GetPropertiesAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(properties.Value.ContentLength);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note for anyone who follows this advice - one bug popped up.  Usually Container.GetBlobClient() automatically escapes characters like #, %, etc that should not be in a URL.  Using Gaurav's recommended method does not do this - instead I was ending up with a full Uri but a truncated Name for the blob - it chops off the offending character and everything after it,  made a bit of a mess - because it does not throw an error, it just saves it under the truncated name.  You have to replace the # with %23 (etc.) before you try to use the blob name.